# LocalDate with Property place holder Spring

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, integration-testing, property-placeholder

I am working with Spring Boot and property placeholders. I have a property file with the value : `date.A=24/07/17`.
I have a class and I am using the `@Value` annotation:

```
@Value("${date.A}")
private LocalDate dateA;
```

But I am getting the runtime error when running `gradle build integrationTest`:

```
Caused by: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '24/07/17' could not be parsed: Invalid value for MonthOfYear (valid values 1 - 12): 24
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(DateTimeFormatter.java:1920)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1855)
    at java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:400)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would need a closer look at the yml file to give the best answer..But here is my hunch-

The expected format is `MM/dd/YY.`

Can you please try changing the yml file to something like this

```
..

date
  A=07/24/17
..
```

Comment: After changing it is working but as per business I want dd/MM/yy

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to write converter for that as follows:

```
public LocalDate convertToDateObject(String value) throws ConversionException {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
    try {
        return LocalDate.parse(value, formatter);

    } catch (DateTimeParseException ex) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: How to incorporate this converter with @Value property place holder ?

Answer (score 0):

The date should be specified in en_US locale, so you need to swap the month and day:

```
date.A=7/24/17
```